# Returning data in function outside Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a function and I want to be able to return my Mongoose query data, so I can use it. However, I can only access sum within the .exec function. How do I get it outside so it gets returned when the functions called?

```
function get_likes(user){
    var Image = require('./models/image');

    var query = Image.find({'author' : user});
    query.exec(function (err, collected) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<collected.length-1;i++){
            sum += collected[i].like_count;
        }

        // I CAN PRINT SUM HERE
        console.log(sum);
        return sum;
    });

    // SUM DOESN'T EXIST OUT HERE.
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Well, variables are scoped to the `function`, so you could declare `sum` above the callback function you're sending to `query.exec()`.
... but none of that is going to matter if that's asynchronous anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly.  node.js uses callbacks and events to handle its asynchronous operations.  Your best bet is to embrace that.

You can indirectly do this by adopting a promise library (http://howtonode.org/promises) but that only kind of fakes synchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

use callback function to respond

```
function get_likes(user, cb){
    var Image = require('./models/image')

    var query = Image.find({'author' : user});
    query.exec(function (err, collected) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

      var sum = 0;
      for(var i=0;i<collected.length-1;i++){
            sum += collected[i].like_count;
        }

        // I CAN PRINT SUM HERE
        console.log(sum);
        cb(sum);
    });

}
```

or if you are using it as an api you can use res.send({"sum": sum});

```
function get_likes(user, req, res){
        var Image = require('./models/image');

        var query = Image.find({'author' : user});
        query.exec(function (err, collected) {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send({"error":"unable to connect"});

          var sum=0;
          for(var i=0;i<collected.length-1;i++){
                sum += collected[i].like_count;
            }

            // I CAN PRINT SUM HERE
            console.log(sum);
            res.status(200).send({"sum": sum});
        });

    }
```

I took node/express as example server.

Comment: The iteration inside the exec function isn't affecting the sum variable. Sum just remains to be 0.

Comment: yes. (query.exec) is and async function.sum will not be available.Pardon me.I will edit the answer.

Comment: How do you call the callback function? What do you pass as the callback parameter?

Comment: it as easy as calling some function with parameters.ex :

Comment: it as easy as calling some function with arguments.
In this example the second parameter is a function(cb).This parameter can be accessed inside get likes function and called.

 EX: get_likes(user, function(sum){
        //USE SUM OVER  HERE.
    });

It is async programming done with callbacks. If you want to get rid of this callback loops use promises.Refer my answer above for definition of get likes.

Answer (score 0):

Your get_likes function is asynchronous so you're supposed to have a callback

```
function get_likes(user, callback){
var Image = require('./models/image');
var query = Image.find({'author' : user});
query.exec(function (err, collected) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<collected.length-1;i++){
        sum += collected[i].like_count;
    }

    // I CAN PRINT SUM HERE
    console.log(sum);
    callback(null, sum);
});
}
```

Comment: So how do I call this? What do I pass to the callback parameter?

Comment: get_likes(user, function(err, sum) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(sum);
    //Do what you want to do with sum
  }
  else{
    //handle your error
  }
});

Comment: Are you sure? You pass a function as the callback?